# How can I programmatically determine (in Python) when someone connects into my windows 7 machine via RDP?

Tags: python, connection, logging, detection, rdp

This doesn't need to be a real time solution, but are there some log files or system messages that could be read to identify periods of time where someone was connected via RDP to a Windows 7 machine?

I'm building a watchdog script for a computer which will be deployed in a remote place and would like to add this metric to a daily status update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the `Event viewer` and the tab `Security` you can find when people login/logout there. Not sure if it gets logged if the session is just disconnected though.

This seems to be a Python library to access the event log: http://timgolden.me.uk/python/winsys/event_logs.html#module-event_logs

Disclaimer: I'm looking at a Windows 2003 server and not Windows 7, so mileage might vary :)

Answer (score 3):

Run with os.system or subprocess module

```
C:\> netstat -n | find ":3389 "

TCP x.x.x.x:3389  y.y.y.y:zzz ESTABLISHED
```

Where, x.x.x.x is own IP and y.y.y.y is remote IP, and zzz is remote port.